# how to calculate cdf using binomial distribution

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

> Question: A lab network consisting of $20$ computers was attacked by a computer virus, this virus enters each computer with probability $0.4$, independently of other computers. Find the probability that it entered at least $10$ computers.

Attempt:
$P(X\geq 10) = 1 - P(X\leq 9) = 1 - F(9)\,\to$ this is as far as I get, how do I calculate the cdf of this ? the solution to it is $0.2447$. We are not using `R` to calculate the answer, how do I do this using a calculator? I am studying for a test and any help on this is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: $\large\frac{23332862537728}{95367431640625}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, seems like your logic is correct. Are you allowed to use a calculator? Seems strange, usually
$$P(X\geq 10) = 1-P(X\leq 9) =1- \sum_{k = 0}^{9}\binom{20}{k}\left(\frac{4}{10}\right)^k\left(\frac{6}{10}\right)^{20-k}$$
is good enough.

For the first term of the sum, we have
$$\binom{20}{0}\left(\frac{4}{10}\right)^0\left(\frac{6}{10}\right)^{20-0} = \left(\frac{6}{10}\right)^{20}=0.00003656.$$

For the second term we have
$$\binom{20}{1}\left(\frac{4}{10}\right)^1\left(\frac{6}{10}\right)^{20-1}=\frac{20!}{1!19!}\cdot\frac{4}{10}\cdot\left(\frac{6}{10}\right)^{19}=0.000487488.$$

Continue for each term, add and subtract from $1$.

You might also be allowed to use a normal approximation.
We know $X\sim \text{Bin}(20, .4)$. Then using a normal approximation, we have
\begin{align*}
P(X\geq 10) &= 1-P(X\leq 9) \\
&\approx1-P\left[Z\leq \frac{9-20(.4)+.5}{\sqrt{20(.4)(.6)}}\right]\\
&=1-\Phi\left[\frac{9-20(.4)+.5}{\sqrt{20(.4)(.6)}}\right]\\
&=0.2467814
\end{align*}
where $Z$ is a standard normal, and $\Phi$ is the usual cdf.

Comment: we are allowed to use a regular calculator, I am using a sharp writeview scientific calculator

Comment: I am not familiar with calculators in general. Can you program it to evaluate sums? You probably can, and if so, get it do sums like the one expressed above. Otherwise, calculate each term of the sum and then add up. However, I ***doubt*** they will have you calculate something like that. It is busy work, and does not test your understanding of the material. You are more likely to calculate something like $P(X\leq 1)$, ***not*** $P(X\leq 9)$, unless you are expected to be able to use approximations.

Comment: Sure, good luck.